# Possibility to let a div change opacity automatically?

Tags: opacity

For my portfolio site I have this idea where I would like the opacity of all thumbnails on the homepage increase and decrease automatically. So when the site is loaded, thumbnail 1 is briefly shown, shortly after it goes blank again, and the process continues with another thumbnail, for example thumbnail 6 and so on. Is there someone who has done this before or has any idea how to realize this idea?

Much appreciation for any comments!

Answer (score 0):

your questions is a long script and need a lot of testing but I will give you some directions.

For time delay

```
    var delay=1000; //1 second

setTimeout(function() {
  //your code to be executed after 1 second
}, delay);
```

This is the easy part inside the {} you put the functionality you like.
Jquery has a neat trick for such tasks

```
.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, complete ] )
```

$( "#ID" ).fadeTo( "slow", 0.33 );

The only thing left is to make a loop that go trough all of your thumbs and fade them in and out.

Hope this helps.